# BHO Execute JavaScript on every page

Tags: c#, c++, internet-explorer, bho

I am write extension for Internet Explorer (BHO).
I read many questions, answers, but can't found and understand, how make execute Javascript file from resource on every page? Not append web page, need necessary execute JS on every page.

I know, that i need make execute after OnDocumentComplete, but i can't know, how do this in C++...
I found this extension, but it is written in C# and i can't convert it to C++.:

https://github.com/dvdotsenko/livereload_ie_extension

I have example BHO in C++:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37044/Writing-a-BHO-in-Plain-C

Can you help me to add execute JavaScript from resource on every page?

Comment: Could you provide feedback with our answers?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [IHTMLWindow2::execScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can get the `IHTMLDocument2` pointer by doing the following:

1. Call `IWebBrowser2::get_Document()`.
2. QueryInterface() the resulting `IDispatch` pointer for `IID_IHTMLDocument2`.

You should be able to get the IHTMLWindow2 pointer by calling `get_parentWindow` on the `IHTMLDocument2` object and doing a similar dance.

Here are some example functions.  You must implement `IObjectWithSite` and cache your site pointer.  You can pass that to these functions.

```
HRESULT Web2FromSite(IUnknown *punkSite, IWebBrowser2 **pWeb2) {
    IServiceProvider* psp;
    HRESULT hr = punkSite->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (void **)&psp);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = psp->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)pWeb2);
        psp->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT Doc2FromWeb2(IWebBrowser2 *pWeb2, IHTMLDocument2 **ppDoc2) {
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spDisp;
    HRESULT hr = pWeb2->get_Document(&spDisp);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && spDisp)
    {
        hr = spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)ppDoc2);
    } else {
        hr = E_FAIL;
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT Doc2FromSite(IUnknown *punkSite, IHTMLDocument2 **ppDoc2) {
    CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> spWeb2;
    HRESULT hr = Web2FromSite(punkSite, &spWeb2);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = Doc2FromWeb2(spWeb2, ppDoc2);
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: I know about this method, but i can't know, how exercise it in C++. In C# it is easier!

Comment: Okay, I updated with some more info.  If you have more specific issues, you can post what you're trying to do, or ask more specific questions.

Comment: I know I ask to write the code for you - not very well.
But could you help with code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose here that you already have a running BHO and that it processes OnDocumentComplete. I also suppose that your processing of OnDocumentComplete get you an IWebBrowser2 interface pointer. Let me know if that's not the case.

warning: error checking "perfectible".

```
HRESULT ExecScriptOnDocComplete(  CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> & spIWebBrowser2, BSTR bstrScriptToExec ) {

    // get the IHTMLDocument2
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spIDispatchDocument;
    HRESULT hr = spIWebBrowser2->get_Document( &spIDispatchDocument );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) return hr;
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spIHTMLDocument2;
    hr = spIDispatchDocument.QueryInterface<IHTMLDocument2>( &spIHTMLDocument2 );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) return hr;

    // get the IHTMLWindow2
    CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> spIHTMLWindow2;
    hr = spIHTMLDocument2->get_parentWindow( &spIHTMLWindow2 );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) ) return hr;

    // Execute the script
    CComVariant ccomvariantRetVal;
    hr = spIHTMLWindow2->execScript( bstrScriptToExec, CComBSTR( L"JavaScript" ), &ccomvariantRetVal );

    return hr;

}
```